# Multi clients (Java swings desk top + mobile + web) in spring 3

Tags: spring, gwt, web-applications

I am relevately new to Web stuff....I am writing a RESTful web application with Spring3 MVC with multiple clients like desktop(java Swings,JavaFX), web client and mobile etc.....Please help and suggests how and which way I design my server and which technologies I use for communication between desktop client and spring web server? How about commons HTTPClient???? I am planning to use GWT for web client. Is GWT recommended?

Also which is good JavaFX or Swings for desktop client?

Does all above make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. Since you have chosen Spring to implement RESTful services, you're server side is already set. I would choose JSON for communication. JSON is  lightweight and is supported by all the client technologies you have listed.

There are client classes in the Spring framework which you can use in your desktop application.

GWT provides the RequestBuilder mechanism to communicate to the server.

As for the mobile client, why not using your GWT web app on the mobile device. See [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) for example.

Comment: Thanks for reply and sorry for the confusion Adrian. This confusion is because there are lots of frameworks available. Which client technology is better to use apart from JSP. Do you mean Rich client or rest template in spring for client?  I only know swings. I am experienced C++ programmer but new to web so my questions may be naive. Any tutorials/examples would be much appreciated and helpful..Thanks